# Angular v2/v4 .js files do not work in modules

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I have a really annoying problem, I tried in every way that I know to solve and nothing worked.

I'm doing a project where I'm using this layout: https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/bike-race-sports-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

Well, actually I'm going to use only the first page of it, the Single Page Layout, I can set up Layout in Angular 2/4 without problems, but when I try to use the modules to separate each section, that's where the inexplicable happens, at least for me.

The .css files continue to run smoothly, but the required .js files stop working, so the page loses all transition functions and effects.

I've tried every way to make it work and I can not do it.

The only way it works and if I mount the entire layout within the index, however as I said I want to use the modules of the Angular to make maintenance easier.

Please help me...

Comment: You have to admit, it's hard to help when no code is provided at all. We don't even know if an error is thrown in the console. It's like calling a mechanic and saying "Hey, my car has a problem, what's the fix?"

Comment: You cannot inject scripts into modules templates in angular. Your only option is to include the .js files on the index (which is sloppy honestly, but should work) or find the libraries via npm and include them in the angular-cli.json file (the "suggested" way, but probably harder to figure out.)